# Update a subdocument with one single query or multiple (mongoose)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is a part of my document:

```
var actions = {

  title: 'Change of windows'
  energySavings:[
  {
     _id: 234324234,
     mainCategory: 'Elektricitet',
     subCategory: 'Belysning',
     value: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 5434534543,
    mainCategory: 'Elektricitet',
    subCategory: 'Utrustning',
    value: 1
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to be able to update energySavings, add items and remove items. This could be done in three separate queries. Or, I could all do it in just one

```
var givenAction = JSON.parse(req.body.action);

mongoose.model('Action').findOne({actionId: req.params.actionId}, function(err, action){

    action.energySavings = givenAction.energySavings;

    action.save(function(err, savedAction){
      res.status(200).send(savedAction);
    });

  })
```

Way less code then three separate queries. However, if the client side programmer makes a mistake, for example empty the entire array and save it, we will have a problem. Is there a best practice to this, make in one query or several with more control?

Comment: You could also notify mongooose the dataset has changed before saving like this: `action.energySavings = givenAction.energySavings; 
action.markModified('energySavings');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also update the document with `findOneAndUpdate` of mongoose. For case the empty array added mistakenly, you need to check `if` the query is empty or not before updating or adding that.

```
var givenAction = JSON.parse(req.body.action);

mongoose.model('Action').findOneAndUpdate({
    actionId: req.params.actionId
}, {
    $set: { 
        energySavings: givenAction.energySavings
    }
}, callback);
```

You can use `$push` to add as new items, and `$pull` to remove items instead of `$set` to updating it. I don't think it is not a good choice to  **update energySavings, add items and remove items** in one query.

Comment: findOneAndUpdate does not go through mongoose validation. So I want to use save().